# Linear map problem

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the steps to solve the problem like this:

Let $\mathcal{X} = (\vec{x}_{1}, \vec{x}_{2}, \vec{x}_{3})$ is base $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ and $\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{L} (\mathbb{C}^{3})$. Find the vector $\mathcal{A}\vec{x}$, provided $\vec{x}= \begin{pmatrix} -2\\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{x}_1= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{x}_2= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{x}_3= \begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathcal{A}\vec{x}_1= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{A}\vec{x}_2= \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{A}\vec{x}_3= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Write $\;x\;$ as a linear combination of $\;x_1,x_2,x_3\;$ :

$$x=ax_1+bx_2+cx_3\;,\;\;a,b,c\in\Bbb C$$

and now use linearity of the map:

$$Ax=aAx_1+bAx_2+cAx_3$$

Comment: and after that?

Comment: "And after that"? I don't know...go listen some music, call some friends...you **already** know what is $\;Ax_1\;$, now multiply this vector by $\;a\;$ , and do the same with $\;bAx_2\;,\;cAx_3\;$ and you get the value of $\;Ax\;$...!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Note that

$$ \overrightarrow{x} = -\overrightarrow{x}_{3} + \overrightarrow{x}_{2} + \overrightarrow{x}_{1} $$

and use the linearity of $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to denote $y_i$ to be $\mathcal{A}x_i$ so I don't have to write out the vectors all the time. If we let $\mathcal X$ denote the matrix whose columns are made up of $(x_1 | x_2 | x_3)$ and similarly $\mathcal Y$ the matrix whose columns are made up by $(y_1 | y_2 | y_3)$ then the whole problem of deriving $\mathcal A$ boils down to solving

$\mathcal A \mathcal X = \mathcal Y$

which can almost be memorized because it's almost what we expect a problem like this to boil down to. Solving this is easy, it's just a matter of inverting $\mathcal X$

Nevertheless, the rationale for this reformulation of the problem is pretty natural so I might as well explain it. A matrix, as we know, is completely determined by how it maps the basis vectors. It's i:th column is precisely the image of the i:th basis-vector.

So how do we translate our knowledge about how $\mathcal A$ maps $x_i$ (which we know) into how it maps the $e_i$s? Well we know that

$\mathcal{X}e_i = x_i$ and $\mathcal A \mathcal X e_i = y_i$ follows directly from this. But since $\mathcal Y e_i = y_i$ the composite map both map the basis vectors in the same way they are the same matrix and we end up with $\mathcal A \mathcal X = \mathcal Y$ as expected.

EDIT: Admittedly this is kind of overkill since all you needed to do was to figure out how it maps a specific vector in which case the other methods presented are more convenient as you don't need the whole matrix for that.